# How do I reverse items from a list and store it as a string in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list where each element is a letter. Like this:

```
myList = ['L', 'H', 'V', 'M']
```

However, I want to reverse these letters and store them as a string. Like this:

```
myString = 'MVHL'
```

is there an easy way to do this in python? is there a .reverse I could call on my list and then just loop through and add items to my string?

Comment: Search "Python how to reverse a list" and "Python how to convert a list to a string"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [`reversed()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), as well as the `[::-1]` negative-stride slice:

```
>>> myList = ['L', 'H', 'V', 'M']
>>> ''.join(reversed(myList))
'MVHL'
>>> ''.join(myList[::-1])
'MVHL'
```

Both get the job done admirably when combined with the [`str.join()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), but of the two, the negative stride slice is the faster method:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(reversed(myList))", 'from __main__ import myList')
1.4639930725097656
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(myList[::-1])", 'from __main__ import myList')
0.4923250675201416
```

This is because `str.join()` really wants a list, to pass over the strings in the input list twice (once for allocating space, the second time for copying the character data), and a negative slice returns a list directly, while `reversed()` returns an iterator instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reversed` (or `[::-1]`) and `str.join`:

```
>>> myList = ['L', 'H', 'V', 'M']
>>> "".join(reversed(myList))
'MVHL'
```